# name files after template bat file - used CMD code

Tags: variables, cmd, rename, filenames, splice

I have a *.bat file in various folders which renames certain files so project number, project name and initials are included in the filename. So far running the file will ask the user to enter project number, project name and initials which are saved as variables (no, project and initial). Each original filename is kept but in brackets will be the required projects specific data). So far it works but what I would like is set up a batch file where the name sets the template for the project specific data e.g.filename of bat file could be:
Rename <XY00.000> (Projectname),XYZ.bat
If in CMD code you could retrieve the filename of the executable bat file (should be only 1 in the folder) and then with delimiters you would splice the filename and store the relevant strings in different variables e.g. what is inside <> will be variable "**no**", whats inside () will be variable "**project**" and what is past the , is "**initial**". If I have those variables the file renaming is as in my current procedure. Please help as I'm not familiar with CMD code or Powershell (which might be alternative option) and it took me long to assemble the existing code. Basically I want to change the input part (see set /p) to something which does:

- get filename of bat file
- extract 3 text strings from the filename (use of delimiters like ( < ,)
- store the 3 text strings as parameters (NO, PROJECT , INITIAL)
- the rest of the existing code should then work to rename the files in the folder

Thanks.

Existing code as example below:

```
cls
    echo off

    pushd "%~p0" 2> nul
    pushd "\\%~p0" 2> nul
    
    echo


attrib -r *.* /s

set /p no= Enter Project Reference in style XY00.000:
set /p project= Enter Project name (without any underscores):
set /p initial= Enter your Initials:


for /f "tokens=1* delims=(" %%i in ('dir /b *.xlsm') do ren "%%i(%%j" "%%i(%no% %project%_%initial%).xlsm"
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=()" %%i in ('dir /b *.docm') do ren "%%i(%%j)%%k" "%%i(%no% %project%_%initial%)%%k"
```

Comment: [1] get the user input with `Read-Host`. [2] get the file names with `Get-ChildItem`. [3] rename the current file with `Rename-Item` & the `.BaseName` of that file & the saved user input. ///// i would use the `-f` string format operator for the last of those.

Comment: thanks for the reply. To be clear the original code works perfect and as far as I can tell your version does the same. My struggle is to change it that you don't need the user input (typing). The idea was that the bat file has a certain name with separators so the code reads out that particular files name and dissects it in different parts which will be safed as variables as mentioned. The renaming of the files already works. Cheers.

Comment: your posted code is BAT/CMD code, not powershell code. do you actually want powershell code? ///// if you want something read from a file, you will need to list the exact steps you want performed. for clarity, do so _as a list_, not a paragraph. i am still unsure what you actually want ... [*blush*]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want a file which is executable and runs some commands in order to rename files which reside in the same folder. So far my patched together cmd code works but the user has to type in the information stored in 3 parameters (No, project and initial).

Comment: I would like to use some automation instead of typing in. If some command can read out the filename of the bat file then this info could then be used. The file is named in a style that you can use delimiters like brackets or commas to separate text bits (project number, project name and initials) and allocate this information to the 3 parameters (no, project, initial). The rest of the command with renaming files should then do its work.

Comment: in text it would be:     1) get filename of *. bat file              2) extract text strings set out by delimiters (brackets, commas...)          3) save 3 strings as parameters    4) rename certain file types in the folder to a defined manner in concatenating parts of original file name + new info from 3 parameters

Comment: please, add those steps [in detail] to your Question so that folks can find them easily.

Comment: ...changed original question.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the user input with:

```
set infovariable=%~n0
```

which safes the filename of the bat file as a variable and uses it later to rename appropriate files with it. The bat file is named exactly what I want as a text. Job done!